# Writing to an MTLTexture causes a fatal error

Tags: ios, objective-c, textures, metal, compute-shader

Given an `MTLTexture`, defined as follows.

```
// Create device.
id<MTLDevice> dev = MTLCreateDefaultSystemDevice();

// Size of texture.
const unsigned int W = 640;
const unsigned int H = 480;

// Define texture.
MTLTextureDescriptor *desc = [[MTLTextureDescriptor alloc] init];
desc.pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;
desc.width = W;
desc.height = H;

// Create texture.
id<MTLTexture> tex = [device newTextureWithDescriptor:desc];
```

It is my understanding that at this point I *should* have a texture as defined in `desc` allocated on device `dev` and accessible through `tex`.

Now, given another texture `tex2` (known to be allocated and accessible) and a Metal compute kernel defined as follows.

```
kernel void foo(texture2d<float, access::read> in [[texture(0)]],
                texture2d<float, access::write> out [[texture(1)]],
                uint2 pix [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    // Out of bounds check.
    if (pix.x >= out.get_width() || pix.y >= out.get_height()) {
        return;
    }

    // Do some processing on the input texture.
    // ... All fine up to here.

    // Write out a pixel to the output buffer.
    const float4 p = abc; // abc is computed above.
    out.write(p, pix);
}
```

It is my understanding that when the pixel `p` is written out to `out`, the values of `p` will be converted to conform to the pixel format of `tex`, in this case `MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm`.

However, when launching the kernel as follows, the line in which `p` is written to `out` (above defined as `tex`) triggers a critical error (`SIGABRT`).

```
// Create a Metal library.
id<MTLLibrary> lib = [dev newDefaultLibrary];

// Load the kernel.
id<MTLFunction> kernel = [lib newFunctionWithName:@"foo"];

// Create a pipeline state.
id<MTLComputePipelineState> pipelineState = [dev newComputePipelineStateWithFunction:kernel error:NULL];

// Create a command queue.
id<MTLCommandQueue> cmdQueue = [dev newCommandQueue];

// Create command buffer.
id<MTLCommandBuffer> cmdBuff = [cmdQueue commandBuffer];

// Create compute encoder.
id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> enc = [cmdBuff computeCommandEncoder];

// Set the pipeline state.
[enc setComputePipelineState:pipelineState];

// Set the input textures (tex2 is read only in the kernel, as above).
[enc setTexture:tex2 atIndex:0];
[enc setTexture:tex atIndex:1];

// 2D launch configuration.
const MTLSize groupDim = MTLSizeMake(16, 16, 1);
const MTLSize gridDim = MTLSizeMake((int)ceil((float)(W / (float)groupDim.width)),
                                    (int)ceil((float)(H / (float)groupDim.height)),
                                    1);

// Launch kernel.
[enc dispatchThreadgroups:gridDim threadsPerThreadgroup:groupDim];
[enc endEncoding];
[enc commit];
[cmdBuff waitUntilCompleted];
```

My question is that under the scenario outlined above, is my understanding of how one allocates a  `MTLTexture` correct? Or, is the example above merely defining a *wrapper* around some texture that I need to separately allocate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above texture allocation and compute kernel launch are correct. Upon further digging in the documentation, the part that was missing was the `usage` property of `MTLTextureDescriptor`. In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexturedescriptor/1515783-usage?language=objc), the following is stated.

> The default value for this property is MTLTextureUsageShaderRead.

As such, in the example given in the question, the following additional property assignment on `MTLTextureDescriptor` is required.

```
desc.usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite;
```